# Comma before "or" in a series?

Tags: grammaticality

Example: "Your answer must be yes, no, or maybe."

Is that correctly punctuated?

Thanks!

Comment: My example was humorously intended, as I suspected that that might indeed be the best answer. :)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. See http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/06/oxford-comma/ , or please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/247569/edit) your post to indicate what research you have attempted in style manuals or punctuation guides.

Answer (score 4):

This is down to particular style. It is in essence an argument over whether or not to use the serial, or Oxford comma.

If you are British, then most style guides would advise against its usage.

If you are American, then most style guides would suggest you use it.

So - funnily enough(!) - the answer is yes, no, or maybe.

Comment: You are saying that 'one variant is incorrect' is a correct opinion.

Comment: My example was humorously intended, as I suspected that that might indeed be the best answer. :)